# GNU make generate assembly first, them compile them to .o and link

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

```
SOURCE=a.c b.c c.c 
ASM=$(patsubst %.c,%.s, $(SOURCE))

all:%.o
    gcc -o test $^

$(ASM):%.c
    gcc -S -o $@ $<

%.o:%.s
   gcc -c -o$@ $<
```

I want to generate assembly code (.s) first, then compile the assembly code to object (.o), then link them.
But it seems above makefile code does not work. What is the correct code?

Answer (score 3):

When asking questions, *does not work* is never very useful... if it worked you probably wouldn't be asking a question! :-)  Instead you should always show the command you ran and the output you received (or at least the failing part of the output if it's long).  Please cut and paste the actual text rather than paraphrasing messages.  Also, including the version of the make program you're using (`make --version`) and the platform you're running on is often helpful.

Luckily this time we can figure out the problem without this information:

This:

```
$(ASM):%.c
        gcc -S -o $@ $<
```

where `ASM` is `a.s b.s c.s`, is not a pattern rule because the targets don't contain a pattern character `%`.  That means the prerequisite `%.c` is not treated as a pattern, but as an actual file name, literally `%.c` which obviously doesn't exist.

Similarly, this:

```
all: %.o
```

has the same problem: `all` is a target, so this depends on the literal file named `%.o` which doesn't exist, and can't be created.

Also as a general rule every recipe that creates a target must create the actual target you told make it would, so this `all` rule is wrong because the target name is `all` but the recipe creates the target `test`.

Finally, it's a very bad idea to name your program `test` because `test` is a common UNIX program and a shell built-in, so if you run `test` it won't do the right thing (if you run `./test` it will work).

You want to have `all` depend on the program you want to build, say `mytest`, and `mytest` should depend on the actual `.o` files:

```
all: mytest

mytest: $(SOURCE:.c=.o)
     gcc -o $@ $^
```

Next, you need to define a pattern rule that knows how to create an assembly file from a source file:

```
%.s : %.c
        gcc -S -o $@ $<
```

That, along with your other pattern rules, is all you need: make will figure it all out from that.

Finally, make has a built-in rule that tells it how to build object files directly from source files.  It's best to get rid of this to force make to use your rules; add this to your makefile to delete it:

```
%.o : %.c
```